# Distinguishing between two QuickFix initiator sessions

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am using QuickFix with Python bindings to connect to a broker and I have two Initiator Sessions in  my config file. One is for the price and the other for the order session.

My question is, say I want to do something when only one of them comes online? If I do

```
initiator = fix.SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)
if initiator.isLoggedOn():
    function()
```

then `function` will be called whether it is the price or order session or both that are logged on. How do I identify when a *specific* initiator session is logged on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the method [`bool Initiator::isLoggedOn()`](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/adb936f95e2cc00af21800c5793880564f2b63e2/src/C%2B%2B/Initiator.cpp#L269) will tell you if any session is currently logged on.

Use [`bool Initiator::isConnected( const SessionID& sessionID )`](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/adb936f95e2cc00af21800c5793880564f2b63e2/src/C%2B%2B/Initiator.cpp#L178) to check a specific session.

[`SocketInitiator`](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/adb936f95e2cc00af21800c5793880564f2b63e2/src/C%2B%2B/SocketInitiator.h#L36) inherits both of these from `Initiator`.

Comment: Hey hunch_hunch. I was looking at that method before I posted, but could not figure out how to make it work. Probably my problem is a lack of C knowledge. Does `isConnected` take two arguments, and what are they? I think i was able to get the sessionID as a string but could not pass it as an argument.  Is it supposed to be a string?

Comment: `isConnected` takes one argument, a [`SessionID`](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/adb936f95e2cc00af21800c5793880564f2b63e2/src/C%2B%2B/SessionID.h) object.

Comment: Have you had any luck getting the session state using `isConnected`?

Comment: I worked on it a little yesterday. I was able yo get a sessionID object (I think) using `getSessions` but there was only one of them. So it wasn't really possible to pass that as an argument to `IsConnected`. How do I get the sessionID of each individual session?

Comment: I'm accepting this, thanks for your help again. If you have any insights on getting individual sessionIDs drop me a note.