# How to get SessionID in QuickFix

Tags: python, python-2.7, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am using QuickFix with Python. On the back of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523954/distinguishing-between-two-quickfix-initiator-sessions) question, I've explored the SessionID class a bit, but I am mystified by the behavior.

The SessionID class is described [here](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/adb936f95e2cc00af21800c5793880564f2b63e2/src/C%2B%2B/SessionID.h). It is formed of a BeginString, SenderCompID and TargetCompID.

Say my SessionID in string form looks like this: FIX.4.2:LMXTS->TS68.

`fix.SessionID().fromString()` returns `:->`

Which if you look, are the three filler characters separating the BeginString, SenderCompID and TargetCompID.

`fix.SessionID().getBeginString` returns `8=☺` (i.e. the BeginString is nowhere). And the same thing applies to `getSenderCompID` and `getTargetCompID`, they return `49=☺` and `56=☺` respectively.

`fix.SessionID().getTargetCompID().getValue()` returns the empty string `''`.

Trying another way, `fix.SessionID().fromString('FIX.4.2:LMXTS->TS68')` returns `None`.

I am trying to get these values *after* the session is created (which I can explicitly see happening when I pass `fix.ScreenLogFactory(settings)` to the initiator. So I am confused.

Comment: What tells you the session is created?

Comment: And did you invoke start()?

Comment: When I start QF in screenLog mode it prints this upon creation `<20150413-17:43:15.863, FIX.4.2:LMXTS->TS68, event>
  (Created session)`. And yes, I tried starting the initiator as well, but got the same results.

Comment: The method [`void onLogon( const SessionID& ) {}`](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/adb936f95e2cc00af21800c5793880564f2b63e2/src/C%2B%2B/Application.h#L114) in `Application.h` is fired when the session is logged on, and gives you a reference to a `SessionID`. You could inspect the `SessionID` object inside `onLogon` to see how it behaves.

Comment: So I was wondering if there was some way of doing something like this and there is. `def onLogon (self, sessionID): print  sessionID` (w proper indentation) gives me exactly what I need. I can call `sessionID.to_string()` within `onLogon` (and I presume in `toApp` etc as well) and distinguish between my sessions this way. It works! If you want to post this as a workaround answer I'll accept. More internet points to thee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`void onLogon( const SessionID& ) {}`](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/adb936f95e2cc00af21800c5793880564f2b63e2/src/C%2B%2B/Application.h#L114) in `Application.h` is fired when the session is logged on, and gives you a reference to a `SessionID`. You could inspect the `SessionID` object inside `onLogon` to see how it behaves.

Comment: Not the actual answer to what's going on with `fix.SessionID` but a great workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it any of the quickfix methods after your session is created as the sesionId is one of the parameters.

The first method fired is onCreate so you can potentially store the sesionId in your class var and then reuse if if and when required to retrieve your settings. You can also use the onLogon method as suggested in one of the other answers.

Example below

```
def onCreate(self, sessionID):
    self.session_id = sessionID
    target = sessionID.getTargetCompID().getString()
    sender = sessionID.getSenderCompID().getString()
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking at the session directly after creating it, before logging on etc. So that means you're not using a breakpoint in, say, FromApp or ToApp to look at the session properties there. If you do, you get the properties directly i.e. SenderCompID, or TargetCompID.

I cannot find the method SessionID in the objects I use. How do you define your 'fix' object?

Comment: Hey rupweb. `fix` is defined like this: `import quickfix as fix`. The method `SessionID` exists, as it doesn't throw an error when I call it. I tried printing `fix.SessionID().toString()` and variants in the `onLogon()` method with the same results. I'll try in `fromApp` and `toApp` and let you know how that goes.

Comment: So, embedding `print fix.SessionID().toString()` in `toApp` and `fromApp` returns `:->`  in both cases (when a message is sent by me, and received by me respectively). What gives?

Comment: can you do fix.SessionID().SenderCompID or fix.SessionID().SenderCompID.toString() or something similar?

Comment: I'll try when I have a minute but don't see any reason to suspect the behavior will be any different than described in the question...